# Auto-populate email address from pc:Person?

Tags: infopath, person

I have a `pc:Person` picker used on an InfoPath form, where they look up their name in Active Directory and select it. The saved form looks like "Last, First" and that's it. There's no way I can see for the manager to see user it is (especially if people have the same first and last name).

How can I add another field to this that auto-populates the email address from the Person picker?

I see that `AccountId` is available under `pc:Person` which is the username, but whenever I try to drag it onto the form it forces a repeating field and I only want this field to correspond to the picked Person picker (one person).

Answer (score 1):

Use GetUserProfileByName operation of UserProfileService.asmx web service. It has Work Email property. Add this on Data Connection and pass the value from your people picker to this Data Connection then query.

See this for detailed steps:
http://thinketg.com/using-infopath-and-the-web-service-getuserprofilebyname/