# Fill Item fields automatically based on Person-Field

Tags: 2013, list, list-workflow

What I want to achieve: Automatic filling of some personal specific fields in a SharePoint List based on a person field like mail address and/or the phone number.

What I have tried so far:

- A List workflow to enter the desired data as soon as the item has been created or changed
- Some experiments with calculated fields (Then I realized that a Person field cannot be used in calculated fields and lookup fields)

Is there anything left to try expect Event Receiver and a JS-Script?

Comment: Which personal details you'd want to populate exactly?

Comment: The Mail address and the phone number.

Comment: It's a lengthy detailing, so I'll just suggest having a look at this article which does the same but with different personal details. You can adjust the implementation for your needs by using the other available details, namely Email address & Phone number. The link: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/anneste/2011/11/02/how-to-create-an-infopath-form-to-auto-populate-data-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Also another link from [SP.SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/158967/auto-populate-email-address-from-pcperson) which forwards to [here](http://eimagine.com/using-infopath-and-the-web-service-getuserprofilebyname/).

Comment: but this is just for informations about the current user right?

Comment: Nope. At least in the link of the second comment there was a requirement description `Even though I needed the information for the current user, I also had a business requirement to retrieve the information for other individuals in the company based on their username` which the article eventually provided a solution.